# How do you access text from an embed on discord.jsv16?

Tags: discord.js

I’m trying to access the footer of an embed, to see if it has specific text. I can’t find the name of what the footer is,

The one I mainly find is message.embed[0].footer, which doesn’t work.

For more context, I’m trying to make a multi-paged help embed, with buttons that go to the next page, and the footer says what page you’re on.

I’m using the footer to detect the page you are on, and know which page to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Message#embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds) which returns an array of [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed)s, get the [`footer`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=footer) from that and get the `text` from it.

```js
const currentPage = message.embeds[0].footer.text
```

Comment: It still says that it cant read it, because footer is undefined

Comment: ok, i’ve found out the problem, message.embed[0] doesn’t work, it doesn’t get defined.